# access to field many2one related

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

hello i want to give an record a domain but ican't access to the field related

this my code python :

```
       class emmployee_e(models.Model):
             _inherit = 'employee.departement'

             employee_parent_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="parent id",related="employee_id.parent_id",store=True)
```

this my xml code

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="parent_action">
        <field name="name">name record</field>
        <field name="res_model">employee.departement</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
         <field name="domain">[('employee_id','child_of', 'employee_parent_id')]
        </field>

        <field name="context">{'search_default_This_Week': 1}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click here to add new message</p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

how to access to this field , i try with id of employee domain works but when i call the field related nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

Here domain is wrong.

```
[('employee_id','child_of', 'employee_parent_id')]
```

*employee_id* refer to *hr.employee* table and you have declared *employee_parent_id* with *res.partner* table which may lead wrong domain. So we need to provide *ids* of *hr.employee*

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you cannot use model `fields` in the right side of the domain tuple because there is no context available to provide the value of that variable to be replaced with a value in order to generate a working sql query.

This is a limitation of Odoo query domains that only works like you are expecting when you use it in a Form view or when you are manually triggering the domain search usage and in both cases the domain should be without quotes in the variable, like:

```
[('employee_id','child_of', employee_parent_id)]
```

And there will be an evaluation context that will provide the specific value of that variable `employee_parent_id`. But it's not intended to work in Menu/View Action domains.